# Running sudo with a specific shell

Tags: command-line, sudo

Suppose the default shell for root is sh, my default shell is zsh, but I want to run a command in csh with sudo.  **How?**

According to `man sudo`, `-l` will give zsh (my shell).

`-i` can give me csh, but only if a user exists that has csh for a default shell and I specify that user with `-u`.  Unfortunately, it also gives the command that user's login environment, which may not be wanted.

Answer (score 2):

```
SHELL=/bin/csh sudo -s
```

will accomplish this.

Comment: The OP says "want to run a command in csh with sudo", why wouldn't he just use `sudo csh -c "command"` ?

Comment: @MarcWilson Ah right, if they only want to run one command that will work as well of course.